# RXJS Stream getting triggered on every checkbox/radio change but expected behavior is to trigger only on form submit

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have two tabs on my UI.

First tab (default) - there is one input textbox and when a user submits it, a http call is sent to the server ( Working as expected)

Second tab - Same input textbox + list of checkboxes & radio buttons, out of which at least one has to be selected. Then on submitting the form, http call is sent.

Now, the problem is - I am aggregating the selected checkbox & radio value when a user submits the form for the second tab. I already have a separate stream for selectedCheckbox & selectedRadioButton which are working as expected. The issue arises after the user submits the form for the first time. On every checkbox/radio change, http call is being sent to the server. I want it to do that only when the form is submitted ( which is also happening). So right now - http call is being sent on form submit( desired) and also on radio/checkbox change ( undesired)

Below is the code snippet.

I am not sure what I am missing. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

```
detailsByAccount$: Observable<MyType> = this.selectedTab$.pipe(
switchMap((tab) => {
   //enteredAccount$ = account submitted through form
  return this.enteredAccount$.pipe(
    switchMap((account) => {

      // Server Http call to get the response
      if (tab === 'X') {
        return this.myService.getDetails(account); // This section works fine
      }

      // After the form is submitted once, this stream is triggered every time, 
     //checkbox is checked or radio button is clicked, probably because both the values are available

        return combineLatest(this.selectedCheckbox$, this.selectedRadio$).pipe(
            concatMap(([selectedCheckbox, selectedRadio]) => this.myservice.getDetails(account, selectedCheckbox, selectedRadio)
        )
      );
      })
      );
    })
  )
```

Comment: [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) will emit the latest value whenever **any** of the observables emits value. If I understood the problem from your snippet correctly, it seems you need to add [`take(1)`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/take.html) to the `combineLatest` observable to stop emitting values.

Comment: But if I do that, will it not unsubscribe as well? I still want to get the values of both checkbox and radio when form is submitted

Comment: Did you consider using `withLatestFrom`? `tabSubmitted$.pipe(withLatestFrom(combineLatest(this.selectedCheckbox$, this.selectedRadio$)))`

Comment: @AndreiGătej - I am not sure how will that work

Comment: @TalOhana - take(1) works as expected. Can you please help me understand how and why? I thought it will unsibscribe this stream. Is it because outer stream is still active and it will resubscribe it again?

Comment: @Vatsal correct, this is because `selectedTab$` is still active, and you don't want to listen to checkbox or radio button changes in-between the outer observable emissions. Please mark it as the answer

Comment: @TalOhana if you post it as answer i will mark it. Comment cant be marked as an answer